# Selectively start Hyper-V at boot on Windows 11 22H2

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, hyper-v, boot-manager

Back on Windows 8, 8.1, and 10, one could have two boot menu entries, with one launching Hyper-V and the other starting Windows without Hyper-V. This was very useful, since I could have Hyper-V around for WSL2 but also use VT-x with VirtualBox, VMware, GVM, HAXM, etc. Come Windows 11 21H2, I had to flip the registry entry `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Hypervisor\HypervisorLaunchType` to 0 to make this keep working, but it worked nonetheless. With 22H2, however, this has stopped having an effect. I have hypervisor-based code integrity off, core isolation off, isolated context disabled, and `hypervisorlaunchtype` set to off in both the registry and the BCD, yet Hyper-V still insists on launching. I've even tried overriding kernel boot parameters in the registry to no avail. Has anyone managed to successfully have Hyper-V disabled without actually uninstalling it on Windows 11 22H2?

Comment: Check if there is a version of Virtual Box that coexists with Hyper-V. I start a Windows Insider machine with Windows 11 Pro 22H2+. If I want Hyper-V I just run it. If I want VMware Workstation (V16+) I just need to start that. No need to select at boot.

Comment: @John VirtualBox does coexist with Hyper-V by running through its API, but the performance is worse, not to mention that some of the other virtualization software I use cannot do that (i.e. anything using HAXM or GVM).

Comment: Virtual box is not a high performance virtual app.

Comment: @John I'm aware that it's not the fastest, but the Hyper-V backend degrades performance compared to just running VBox with direct VT-x access. VBox is the only choice for some applications (e.g. Genymotion)

Comment: A natively built in Hyper-V works fine here.

Comment: @John Like I said, Genymotion *requires* VirtualBox and VBox only, and there are a couple other times when I want or need VBox specifically. Either way, I found how to selectively disable Hyper-V on boot, so this is moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was virtualization-based security that had been enabled through my university's Group Policy. Taking my machine off of the domain and disabling all virtualization-related security features let the old BCD and Registry trick keep working.